# Add customfields in the administration section of a module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, xml

Is there a way, to load with an XML element, the custom fields, from the Joomla component, com_fields in the backend of a module?
I know how to take them from the default.php and display them, but I was wondering if there is a way to load them in the backend of a module administration and then reproduce them like a repeatable field?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour].

Comment: Short answer is no. Slightly longer answer is why would you want that? Or put another way: why would a subform in the module's xml config not be sufficient?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I am developing a module and I want to store besides the repeatable fields values, informations like when the field was created or edited and by whom. So I thought that by creating a custom field and by the time is stored in the database I could acces thise kind of informations.

Comment: Sounds like you need a component

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a content plugin quite easily. See [this guide](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_content_plugin) for starters.

You create the XML in your plugin `form/modwhatever.xml`. Now you can add whatever fields you wish - you might want to look at the articles form for examples of user, publishing dates etc, which can be located in `administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml`.

Your plugin would implement a method like so:

```
    public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
    {

        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = $app->input->get('option');

        switch ($option) {

            case 'mod_whatever':

                if ($app->isAdmin()) {

                    JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');

                    $form->loadFile('modwhatever', false);

                }

                return true;

        }

        return true;

    }
```

To ensure you don't need to apply any further changes, you can use the `attribs` form as a basis so that your new fields are available on the modules params, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
  <fields name="attribs">
     <fieldset name="customstuff" label="Custom Stuff">
        <field 
            name="created_by" 
            type="user"
            label="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_CREATED_BY_LABEL" 
            description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_CREATED_BY_DESC" 
        />

        <field 
            name="created_by_alias" 
            type="text"
            label="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_CREATED_BY_ALIAS_LABEL" 
            description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_CREATED_BY_ALIAS_DESC"
            size="20" 
        />
     </fieldset>
  </fields>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you Grant G . I implemented with simple repeatable fields. But I have another question. Where are the repeatable field values stored in the database?

Comment: @leno1232 I answered on your other question. Depending on how you added the fields, it is entirely possible that they are _not_ saved to the database. For instance, if your XML sets a name `<fields name="doesnotalreadyexist">`, then it will not save.

Comment: thank you for answering my questions! I am grateful!

Comment: @len Please take our [tour] and then please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329